Is an entirely sailing-ship based civilization feasible?
I'm picturing a city-state was destroyed by rising sea levels. Rather than scatter or build dams to protect the city, they took to the seas, a 'city-fleet' of sailing ships that travels the oceans fishing and raiding.
Before I start working out details like population, ship types, culture, and magic, I want to know: is such a thing feasible? Would they be able to believably sustain themselves while still traveling as a fleet?
Since the ultimate fate of this civilization is to be wiped off of the map by a localized event (angry sea goddess), the majority of the people do have to be on the ships (it can't just be the naval force of a land-based people) and the majority of the ships do all have to be traveling together.
Potentially relevant setting details:

The world is much more aquatic than Earth. The continents are smaller, and islands are much more common.
Mermaids and other aquatic cultures exist. Potential sources for trade.
'Medieval' is my starting assumption for technology level. This is not locked in.


Feasible? What does that mean to you? It'll be believable if you build the structure of your world to support this type of civilization. Are you worried that people might judge your idea "unrealistic?" Keeping in mind that the highest grossing movies of all time have been superhero movies. I ask because SE is a solve-your-problem site, not an review-your-idea site. We have difficulty with review-your-idea question because they fail a bunch of SE's rules (open-ended, opinion-based, hypothetical, etc. see [help/dont-ask]).

You want your civilization to survive natural disasters: on land this would be earthquakes, floods, volcanic eruptions. On the open sea it will be storms: much, much more frequent. We stick to solid ground for a reason.

@JBH That's fair. I may rewrite the question to something more like "How could this civilization solve [X] problems", but currently, I don't really have a good idea of what those problems would be, so I started with this question.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanka_people

I don't quite see why an angry sea goddess couldn't wipe out a land-based civilization on an island. The story so far seems to imply that, in fact, she already did - the city-state was swallowed by the sea.

they will not be very successfull at a raiding medieval cultures, they will not be numerous or as well equiped as people who live on land. And they are not getting anywhere near medieval technology. But if they just need to survive largely on the ocean there are real world people who do that.

Life on land is always more sustainable than life at sea, even if they could survive, they will eventually want to find a little piece of whatever land they can find, and take it by force if they must.

@Nosajimiki several extant tribes / ethnic groups of boat nomads would beg to differ, once a lifestyle and way of living becomes sufficiently culturally engrained it can prove quite durable even in the face of being offered or even on occasion external attempts to force a different way of doing things.

This was a movie famous because it flopped hard.

@Pelinore Exactly, but they are not starting as boat nomads, they are starting as islanders.

Aside from Waterworld obviously, Jack Vance had something quite similar in The Blue World

"Would they be able to believably sustain themselves while still traveling as a fleet?"  Believability is suspension of disbelief.  Disbelief is suspended when you write a competent story, with compelling characters that you care about.


How long do the ships last?
Historically, a single season in tropical waters could ruin a wooden hull. Shipworms, rot, storms, and so on. Wooden ships would be careened every couple of months, pulled onto a beach and scraped. How do they do that on the water? If they cannot, the ships will last a few years.
Magic might help here.
Where do the ships come from?
Regardless of how long the ships last, there will have to be new ones. Historically, this starts by growing large trees, cutting them, drying them, assembling the frame and planking them. That is done on land.
Imagine very large rafts where ships are built. There would still be the question of where the materials come from, and also where the large rafts are assembled. In sections on other rafts?
Where do they get food?
Fish and seaweed are probably not a balanced diet. Knowing which seafood contains which vitamins and trace minerals might help, but can they find all of those in sufficient quantity? Is that where the trade with the merfolk comes in?

Or consider a situation where the "sea people" and the "land people" are distinct ethnic groups, yet mingling all the time in the ports. The "sea people" buy ships from the "land people" and crew them, paying with the money they earn by hauling freight for the landlubbers who do not dare to cross the ocean. (Yet how do the "land people" manage to build good ships if they never sail them?)
Look at the trade winds and seasonal travel in history. Say your ships are not very good at tacking against the wind, so all those who want to make the trip that year start out at roughly the same port, at roughly the same time, to catch the trade wind. All those who do not join will not earn money that year ...

As an addition to your comment about food you also need to think about water. If these people sail an ocean fresh water might be one of the most important resources. In ancient times fresh water was basically the fuel of rowed ships as rowers drank up to 8 liters a day. Sailing would reduce that drastically but fresh water would remain a key  resource. A man has lived for 438 days lost at sea living of fish, but such diet isn't balanced and prone to disease like scurvy.

@GreedyGroot Cooked roe (fish eggs), clams, algae including macro algae such as seaweed .. all contain fair amounts of vitamin C with which to avoid scurvy .. around 4 clams will very nearly contain your daily dose or thereabouts, it's more a case of what we know and do as land living animals doesn't turn much of it up than it's not there, vitamin C exists in ocean food webs its just not where 'we' normally look for it .. rainwater can always be collected, and seawater can also be distilled with some fairly simple equipment, but you should be able to meet your fluid needs from fish blood etc.

@GreedyGroot "it's more a case of what we know and do as land living animals doesn't turn much of it up than it's not there" .. and besides that scurvy is a disease of sailors subsisting on dry rations during long voyages rather than of fishermen subsisting on sea food, most fish will have some in it, they're animals too and need it for their bodies the same as we do.

@GreedyGroot, I added another sentence. :-) Not just vitamin C but a whole raft of nutrients.

The question does state there are many islands, so careening is possible, or maybe they haul some sort of makeshift drydock which can be deployed on suitable beaches. And islands also can sort out other food resources.

For materials: maybe have forests of tough, fibrous "kelp" that can be harvested for fiber and woven into thick, tough matting?  Those mats could be layered together to form a reasonably-waterproof hull.  Alternative possibilities: laminated tanned marine-animal skins.  Both woven kelp fiber and tanned skins could be used for sails, and rope (for sailhandling, lashing the mats and skins into cohesive hulls, etc.) could be made from spun kelp fiber or the sinews of marine animals.

A sailing fleet needs sails
I upvoted o.m.'s answer, but there is an additional key supply issue - textiles.  After food production, textile production was the most time-consuming activity for pre-industrial societies.  Note that for most societies the uses of textiles were primarily for clothing and bedding - curtains, wall hangings and rugs for the floor were luxuries for the rich.  However, by definition the proposed sailing city-state requires sails for every vessel - this requires an enormous amount of canvas, with a limited lifespan in constant use.
Sailing vessels also require large amounts of cordage - ropes of various strengths and diameters for rigging and other uses.  Cordage was also extremely time-consuming to produce, it is only less notable in pre-industrial economies because the quantity required was relatively low for land-dwellers.
With medieval technology there is no feasible way for the fleet to produce the textiles (primarily canvas) and cordage it requires.  (Actually, while the city was still on land it would have been unable to produce or buy enough sailcloth and cordage to take to the sea in the first place.)  It is implausible to believe that there are sufficient warehouses full of canvas and cordage waiting to be looted anywhere, let alone in settlements small enough that raiding will be successful.  (Note that the naval battles required for raids will result in the loss of both canvas and cordage, as the sails and rigging of a sailing ship are routinely targeted.)
I am not even going to start on metalwork - I believe the fleet would have enormous difficulty replacing iron objects as they rust out in the sea air, but it is less of a problem than the textiles.
TL;DR even if the fleet can somehow magically overcome the issues of ship repair/replacement and food/water that o.m. raised, they will be literally dead in the water due to lack of sails unless immense quantities of sailcloth and rigging can be magically conjured from nothingness.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyester shoulf be synthesizable on a medieval ship?

@Pica the article you link mentions the first research into polyester was in 1926 - that's not remotely medieval.  I'll admit I have no idea about how feasible it would be to source the precursor chemicals at sea if it was a modern-tech fleet, need to rely on someone with more chemistry knowledge for that.

It also mentions, that a ton of polyester are naturally produced by some living creatures. And you can catch those creatures, extract those polyester from the remains and recast them into - a ship.

Wrong article sorry - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biopolymer

@KerrAvon2055 the question isn't when we did it but when it could be done, which can differ quite a lot because there was no incentive to find alternatives to sheep, cotton, flax etc.

Metalwork's mostly not a problem: just about everything that was historically done with iron could be done with corrosion-resistant bronze instead.  Iron was used because it was much cheaper than bronze, not because it was better.

@Mark agree totally, though 1) an ocean-going fleet can't mine or refine any of the metals it needs, whether iron, copper, tin etc; and 2) the limitations of fire danger, available space and fuel supply mean that they won't be forging and will have difficulty even smithing any metals on a medieval ship.  I think metalwork is probably still a deal-killer unless they can loot or trade for vast quantities - look at the economics of the fleets built for the Punic Wars - but the textiles issue is much more clear-cut, which is why I focused on it.

@pica,  yes that is what was used in medieval times,  canvas is cellulose, wool is keratin, leather is collagen etc... but that does not address the supply issue.

@KerrAvon2055 Just one little thing I'd like to point out.  Fire danger isn't as severe as you might think, surprisingly enough.  Whalers would often boil the blubber while at sea; imagine what a fire hazard that must've been.  Open flame, large containers full of oil, rolling decks.  If they could handle that I'd think the OP's society could handle it too.

For rope: maybe have some sort of fibrous seaweed or marine plant that can be harvested for fibers, or use marine-animal sinews?  For sails, weave those same fibers into cloth, or use tanned marine-animal skins.

@KerrAvon2055 Forging is totally possible aboard a ship albeit difficult. Cutty Sark's crew famously manufactured a replacement rudder for it from spare wood and iron while in a gale.

We have people like that right now. The Bajau people have been living on the sea since prehistory, long enough that they have evolved special physical adaptations for diving.
They've been doing it since the stone age so your people shouldn't have an issue. They live off the sea and trade surplus with land dwellers for essentials.
Also fleets of sailing ships could and did spend years at sea, only coming to land to trade, shoot some natives, dispense some diseases and refit their ships. Captain Cook & Abel Tasman for example.

note they had to come to land for wood and fiber fairly often. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sama-Bajau and therir technology is still at essentially stone age level.

@John some of their tech is stone age, as is ours. But they have metal pots and pans and tools

I would suggest rewriting some of the ecosystem of your planet to make it feasible:

Make sailcloth easy. Suppose there is a type of kelp that can be easily farmed for fiber, then spun and woven for cloth, while on a ship. This would help making enough sailcloth. Or maybe the kelp even grows in convenient "sheets" that can be used as-is.
make ships last. Suppose the main wood the shipwrights use is as durable as black locust, and so full of tanins or or even poisons to discourage shipworms and barnacles.
Make fisheries great (again?) Suppose the super-kelp seas are particularly fertile with life. Maybe the kelp itself is edible as well. Maybe it is improbably rich with fish and krill.
Booty- full Bounty. Maybe the seas are rich with something profitable, like pearls? That would explain how the Seafarers can afford stuff.

Idea: The Deep-Trees.
The Deep Trees are unrelated to terrestrial trees, but a specific species of kelp that evolved to be the underwater equivalent of sequoias. Imagine incredibly tall trunks that extend from the bottom of a shallow seas, and grow giant kelp "leaves" on the surface. The space under the leaves is swarming with fish, shrimp, and sea-cows (manatees). The Deep Trees produce "fruit": fist sized globs of sweet mush filled with vitamins and nutritiends, that the sea-cows and mermaids eat. The seeds inside the fruit are extremely dense and hard, impervious to water, bacteria and sealife, and look like black pearls. Similarily, the wood of the Deep Tree is near-indestructible, completely impervious to seaworms, barnacles and rot. Floats like foam, despite being stronger than oak, more elastic than yew, and over time, changes into a sea version of coal.
The Deep Trees are perfect resource for the Seafarers. But exploiting them destroys mermaid habitat. But who cares about mermaids, eh?

For #2, oooh, maybe that wood's from trees that evolved in a coastal environment with their feet in the sea, and they evolved to be unpalatable or toxic specifically because of evolutionary pressure from shipworms?

If it "floats like foam" -- how do the trees stay submerged? Especially the saplings.

@ivan_pozdeev, that the point, it does not need to. The ocean's bottom is not all that particularly rich in nutrients, so if the "soil" is to thin for the roots to keep the tree anchored, it gets pulled out and pushed by currents to another location until it gets stuck and rooted again, by extending root tendrils down and "righting" itself. Saplings travel this way to conquer new environments.

If the tree floats, it won't be able to stay upright. Unless its underwater part is sufficiently bigger and heavier that the above-water one, that is...

In general, trees tend to be bottom heavy so yes.

Ceramics is as old as mankind, but brittle. A medieval fleet of sailing ships could have a thin ceramics layer on the inside It would be brittle. So it could not be load bearing, but water and withering protection .
English ships had metal plating for the hulls, the demand for anti shipworm measures is what started the industrial revolution there.
Closest we got in real life was venecia.
Also, there is naturally occuring plastics like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer#Natural
Catch all the turtles, cook all the turtleshells down into purerish plastics, inject it into a ship part mold.
